# Can't edit database fields in myLittleAdmin for SQL Server 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Whenever I create a new table in a database and add some data to it I then cannot edit that data. I can do everything else - rename columns, add new columns, delete columns, write new data. I just cannot edit existing data.

What's interesting is that for tables that existed before I started working on the database, I can edit existing data. This problem is only happening for tables I create. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a primary key defined on your table.
Check this KB
http://forum.mylittleadmin.com/yafnet/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=359